# How to display MultiSelect Option Set in Dynamics 365 Web Portal with Liquid Template

Tags: templates, liquid, microsoft-dynamics, portal, fetchxml

I'm trying to display the selected values of a MultiSelect Option Set in a custom page in Web Portal with Liquid Template.

I wrote the FetchXml query anf if i test it the query in XrmToolBox, it's return the field with values.

But when Liquid Template executes the query in the Web Template, the field is null or empty :

```
{% fetchxml areas %}
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="ioc_role">
    <attribute name="ioc_roleid" />
    <attribute name="ioc_functionalarea" />
    <order attribute="ioc_personid" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="ioc_roleid" operator="eq" value="{{myGuid}}"  />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
{% endfetchxml %}
{% for item in areas.results.entities %}
    <span>{{item.ioc_functionalarea}}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

The result by XrmToolBox :

```
<resultset>
    <result>
        <ioc_roleid>
            {74D55E06-175F-E911-A966-000D3A441525}
        </ioc_roleid>
        <ioc_functionalarea name="[-1,182090000,182090001,182090003,-1]" >
            [-1,182090000,182090001,182090003,-1]
        </ioc_functionalarea>
    </result>
</resultset>
```

Do you have any idea about this behavior?

Comment: Not aware of Liquid Template but could you not Test your Fetchxml in Liquid Template with Static Guid, the way you did it in XRMToolBox. See what results you get.

Comment: same result without filters

Answer (score 0):

item.ioc_functionalarea is an array,
You probably have to try like

item.ioc_functionalarea[0]

This will give 1st multi select value.

Also just to check could you show roleid,
I mean just to be sure you do get roleid in your liquid template.

Answer (score 0):

I get the good item when I display the roleid.
I tried :

`item.ioc_functionalarea.size => nothing
item.ioc_functionalarea | size => 0
item.ioc_functionalarea | join: ',' => nothing`